# Request client certificate through code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl-certificate

There is an option in IIS to request client certificate, but I am wondering if there is any way to do that through code. Any way to extend the RequireHttpsAttribute action filter to require client certificate?

I don't care for the automatic certificate-user mappings or any of that, as longs as I can get the certificates from Request.ClientCertificate I'm good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that is possible, because the client certificate negotiation is not part of the http protocol. It is deep in the TSL protocol which is not easily (if at all) accessible from your code.

This [TechNet blogpost](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2013/12/30/how-it-works-on-the-wire-iis-http-client-certificate-authentication.aspx) describes what happens during a client certificate negotiation with IIS.

IIS allows you to require a client certificate just for a specific URL, so change your code to use one URL when you need a client certificate and another one if you don't.